# Any differential geometry with metric structure book recommendation

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation, geometric-measure-theory, ricci-flow

I am currently reading the book 'Application of Ricci flow' by Bennett Chow which mentions the Cheeger-Gromov Convergence and local collapsing stuff by Perelman. I would like to have a better understanding of those 'collapsing', pointed manifold convergence stuff.

Is there any good book recommendation for me to study?

Comment: For the convergence theorem, I recommend reading the papers by Greene-Wu and Stefan Peters about this. Cheeger's original JDG paper is also worth looking at. All of the essential ideas are in there. What Gromov did was to generalize the concept of Haudsorff distance and observe that Cheeger's theorem implied the compactness theorem.

Comment: A Course in Metric Geometry by Burago, Burago, Ivanov covers everything you mention.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I will read them later